# Javascript Not able to call functions inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript code:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(':radio').each(function() { // loop through each radio button    
        //Code to check for radio button selected - Works
    });   
    //A 
});
```

Code works well. But if add code like the below one in place of //A then error comes that trim() is not defined. But i am using other jquery functions above and they are working. Also i am not able to call any function(user defined) from the location //A.

```
var textboxes = $('input:text');
textboxes.each(function() {    
    attrval = $(this).attr("val");
    attrval =  trim(attrval);  // Error Line    
});
```

Is something wrong with the scope here?

Comment: `$.trim()`........

Comment: There's no built in JavaScript `trim` function, so you'll need to show us where you're declaring it yourself (or change it to use jQuery's `$.trim()`).

Comment: Please read the documentation before asking questions like this. I beg you.

Comment: where and how are trim and/or your other "user defined" functions defined? If they are in the global scope, they will be accessible, if they are defined with var then they will only be accessible within the function scope where they are defined.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: There is in "modern" browsers, `String.prototype.trim`

Comment: I am calling the trim() of Jquery. Also as i mentioned i am not able to call any function that i have defined before as well. I Have included the files with jquery first and all other js files before including this file.

Comment: ok got. it. $.trim() :)

Answer (score 3):

This the syntax to perform the `trim()` function:

`$.trim('  your string   ');`

Answer (score 0):

you can also use pure javascript:

```
attrval.trim();
```

`trim()` exists since Javascript 1.8.1: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Or you can use jQuery as mentioned:

```
$.trim( attrval );
```

Comment: You can't use `attrval.trim()` because JavaScript doesn't implement a trim function.

Comment: are you sure? http://jsfiddle.net/pztbR/3/

Comment: Seems you were right. `trim()` did not exist until v1.8.1 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Answer (score 0):

i think you sholud call

```
$.trim(attrval)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do this:

```
  var textboxes = $('input:text');
  textboxes.each(function() {    
  attrval = $(this).attr("val").trim();
```